# DS2413 One Wire IC read and store the addresses of individual IC's

Tags: c++

Hy,
Here I using 10 DS2413 to control gpios, it works very well with arduino ,I read the 10 ic address and store it in a 2D array, I want to control the individual IC using their address .Here all works well. My problem is the Ic address are not store in arrange wise manner. For ex, I have 10 IC's, Each IC's have unique address, The address of first IC1 is store in arr1, address of ic2 is arr2 and address of ic3 is store in arr3..... what i need is If i Swap the IC1 and IC2 the address of IC2 is store in arr1 and IC1 address is store in arr2.

Comment: Can you show us the sketch you're using?

Comment: 1-wire has no concept of bus position, only the logical order of the ROM addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The OneWire system has no concept of the arrangement of the bus. All it knows is the addresses, and it always searches for those addresses in a pre-defined order.

No matter what arrangement you have on the bus the devices will always be found in the same order.

You can think of it akin to a teacher taking the register in class. They call out the names in alphabetical order and the pupils answer (if they are there). All it tells the teacher is who is there and who isn't. It doesn't give them any information about where in the class the pupil is sat.

You can read more about how the address searching is done [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/1/187.html).